# Tkinter layout question

Tags: python, tkinter

Tricky to explain with words so I'll use a picture.

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

```
A: row 0, column 0
B: row 0, column 1
C: row 1, column 0, span 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
A: row 0, column 0, sticky=W
B: row 0, column 1, sticky=W
C: row 1, column 0, span 3
grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you *can't* see in that picture is the big element `D` in the third slot of the 3-element hbox that's in the first slot of the 2-element vbox.